# How to use the `od` command to check HDD zeroization?

Tags: command-line, bash, hard-drive, security

I want to check if a hard disk drive has been successfully zeroed. I read [this](https://superuser.com/a/559855), which instructs to run:

```
$ sudo od /dev/disk2 | head
```

which for his HDD returns:

```
0000000    000000  000000  000000  000000  000000  000000  000000  000000
*
234250000
```

I've read [here](http://www.linfo.org/head.html) that

> `head` returns the first ten lines of each file name that is provided
>   to it.

1. Am I right in assuming that without `| head`, `od` will print the entire HDD contents to terminal?
2. When I tried this, I got the same output: 1 seven-digit `0`s and 8 six-digit `0`s and 1 `*`, except that after the `*` I get `7216060060000`. Is everything up to and including the `*` the ten "lines" (though this isn't a file and there shouldn't be any lines)?
3. Why is only the first number seven digits?
4. What does the `*` mean? Does it mean that everything else can be anything (not necessarily zeroes), are all zeroes (i.e. my whole HDD is all zeroes), or are all the same preceding pattern repeating (i.e. 1 seven-digit `0`s and 8 six-digit `0`s)?
5. The [`od` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html) states the `od` command will: "Write an unambiguous representation, octal bytes by default, of FILE to standard output." What is an "octal byte"? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467363/is-this-definition-on-an-octal-byte-correct) suggests it is nonstandard terminology but might be 6 bits.
6. My HDD is 500 GB with 512-byte sectors. Does this `7216060060000` equal that capacity?

   7216060060000 octal bytes * (6 bits? / 1 octal byte?) * (1 byte/8 bits) * (1 GB/1e9 bytes)
   = 5412.045045 GB

   which isn't my HDD capacity. Did something go wrong?
7. Was my HDD successfully zeroed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No. `head` will cut off output after 10 lines by default. Since there were only three lines total in the output, you'll get only three lines with or without `head`.
2. As for lines, why should only files have [lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)? Do you want all command output to be stuffed into one line?
3. It's an octal number showing how many bytes have been read since the start of the input. It can be more digits if needed.
4. From [`man od`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/od.1.html):

   ```
   -v, --output-duplicates
         do not use * to mark line suppression
   ```

   So `od` tries to avoid printing duplicate lines. `*` marks those.
5. From [the original `od` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/od-invocation.html#od-invocation) (which is clearer):

   > Each line of output consists of the offset in the input, followed by
   >   groups of data from the file. By default, od prints the offset in
   >   octal, and each group of file data is a C short int’s worth of input
   >   printed as a single octal number.

   So each block as a whole is an octal number. A C `short int` is [usually 2 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12280274/2072269). `od` takes two bytes worth of data, treats it as a number, and prints it in base 8 as a single number, and repeats. Each line has 8 such blocks, so we have 16 bytes per line. The offset is also printed in base 8, and 20 in base 8 is 16 in base 10.
6. Since the offset is in base 8, converting to base 10:

   ```
   $ echo $((8#7216060060000))
   500107862016
   $ echo $((8#7216060060000 / 1000 / 1000 / 1000))
   500
   ```

   `$((N#X))` tells bash to read `X` as a base-`N` number. Since bash outputs in base 10 by default, doing `$((8#...))` converts from octal to decimal.
7. Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a bunch of questions here, this is answering #5, octal output represents binary data three bits to a digit, each digit will have a value from 0-7, with 0 = binary 000, 1 = binary 001, 2 = binary 010, 3 = binary 011,
4 = binary 100, 5 = binary 101, 6 = 110, and 7 = 111.  Octal was popular with ancient computer systems but hex which uses 0-f to represent values 0000 through 1111 in each digit is more compact and used more frequently today.